# Using incoming data from bluetooth connection for specific objects? C# Windows Form App & Java Android App

Tags: java, c#, android, bluetooth

first post here. I've tried to look for a question I have but no luck so I figure I ask it myself.

I am working on 2 programs. An Android app in Java and a C# Windows Form App on windows. They are both simply scorekeeping calculators to keep track of the score of 2 players.

The goal of the 2 programs is to use a Bluetooth connection to send data back and forth between each other so that they are "synced". Android app is a client, c# app is a server (32feet library).

Using the Bluetooth Chat example on Android and some code i put together in VS, I managed to get the 2 programs to connect and send and receive data to each other, great!

But now my main goal is that I need to find out a way to take the incoming data coming from the Android app and change the appropriate labels/text on the windows app.

So for example:

- on the Windows App, there are 2 Labels: one for Player1, one for Player2 that both say "10".
- On the Android App, I have 2 buttons that separately subtract from either Player1 or Player2's score.
- On the android app, if I touch the button that subtracts(-) 1 from Player1 it would be 9. I now want that change to apply to Player1's score label on the windows app, where it would also show 9.
- I then want the same thing for Player2's score.

This is the best I can describe my goal, and I would like to know if it's possible, and if so, be pointed in the right direction.

Here is some provided code for what I have so far:

C# windows form app:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (serverStarted == true)
            {
                updateUI("Server already started");
                return;
            }
            if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                connectAsClient();
            }
            else
            {
                connectAsServer();
            }
        }

        private void connectAsServer()
        {
            Thread bluetoothServerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ServerConnectThread)); //creates new thread and runs "ServerConnectThread"
            bluetoothServerThread.Start();
        }

        private void connectAsClient()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        Guid mUUID = new Guid("fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66");
        bool serverStarted = false;


        public void ServerConnectThread()
        {
            serverStarted = true;
            updateUI("Server started, waiting for client");
            BluetoothListener blueListener = new BluetoothListener(mUUID);
            blueListener.Start();
            BluetoothClient conn = blueListener.AcceptBluetoothClient();
            updateUI("Client has connected");

            Stream mStream = conn.GetStream();

            while (true)
            {

                try
                {
                    //handle server connection
                    byte[] received = new byte[1024];
                    mStream.Read(received, 0, received.Length);
                    updateUI("Received: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(received));
                    byte[] sent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hello world");
                    mStream.Write(sent, 0, sent.Length);
                }
                catch (IOException exception)
                {
                    updateUI("Client disconnected");
                }
            }
        }

        private void updateUI(string message)
        {
            Func<int> del = delegate ()
            {
                textBox1.AppendText(message + Environment.NewLine);
                return 0;

            };
            Invoke(del);
        }

    }
```

Android App (snippet from the Bluetooth Chat example - i think this is the only relevant part):

```
    /**
     * Sends a message.
     *
     * @param message A string of text to send.
     */
    private void sendMessage(String message) {
        // Check that we're actually connected before trying anything
        if (mChatService.getState() != BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.not_connected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        // Check that there's actually something to send
        if (message.length() > 0) {
            // Get the message bytes and tell the BluetoothChatService to write
            byte[] send = message.getBytes();
            mChatService.write(send);

            // Reset out string buffer to zero and clear the edit text field
            mOutStringBuffer.setLength(0);
            mOutEditText.setText(mOutStringBuffer);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to have to add the clients to alist of streams for reference and also store the scores of each client on a list and then send the data coming from each client to the rest of the clients 
so from the server youd have basically something like this

```
List<Stream> clients=new List<Stream>();
List<String> client_scores=new List<String>();
    public void ServerConnectThread()
    {
        serverStarted = true;
        updateUI("Server started, waiting for client");
        BluetoothListener blueListener = new BluetoothListener(mUUID);
        blueListener.Start();
        BluetoothClient conn = blueListener.AcceptBluetoothClient();
        updateUI("Client has connected");

        Stream mStream = conn.GetStream();
    clients.add(mStream);
    client_scores.add(new Random().Next()+"");
    int index_cnt = clients.IndexOf(mStream);

        while (true)
        {

            try
            {
                //handle server connection
                byte[] received = new byte[1024];
                mStream.Read(received, 0, received.Length);

                updateUI("Received: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(received));
                client_scores[client_scores.FindIndex(ind=>ind.Equals(index_cnt))]       =  Encoding.ASCII.GetString(received);
                byte[] sent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hello world");
                mStream.Write(sent, 0, sent.Length);
                foreach(Stream str in clients)
                {
                 byte[] my_score = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(clients.ToArray()[index_cnt]+"");
                str.Write(my_score, 0, my_score.Length);
                }
            }
            catch (IOException exception)
            {
                updateUI("Client disconnected");
            }
        }
    }
```

You can then serialize the data being sent in some sort of json so as to send multiple fields of data comfortably for example :

```
{
  "data type": "score",
  "source_id": "client_unique_id",
  "data": "200"
}
```

On your displaying side,just get the values of (in our example case source_id and data) and display on a label